# WordPress WooComerce background customization

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

total beginner here, so apologies if this is not the place to post.

my site has a white background throughout but woocomerce has an annoying gray background around the edges of its pages (cart, checkout, product pages), and i was able to figure out that by adding the following code to Customize CSS section of my site fixed the problem

.woocommerce-cart, .single-product { background: white; }

BUT I cannot find the value to use for "checkout page" to change its background to white. i tried .woocomerce-checkout and woocomerce_checkout and .checkout. no luck :( any advice?

Answer (score 1):

The body class of the woo-commerce checkout page is correct what you have mentioned (**.woocommerce-checkout**).

Please try adding **!important** flag to CSS property.

```
.woocommerce-checkout { background: white !important; }
```